# Referring to private inner classes by short name?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Consider the folllowing nested class structure:

```
public class Foo {
  private class Bar {
    private class Zub {
    }
  }

  void foo() {
    Bar.Zub z = ...; // <-- I'd like to use `Zub z =` here w/o qualifying with Bar
  }
}
```

Within a function in the outmost class, such as `Foo.foo()`, I would like to refer to `Foo.Bar.Zub` by its short name `Zub`, rather than the qualified name `Bar.Zub`.

Normally an import statement would suffice, like `import package.Foo.Bar.Zub`, but this fails here because `Bar` and `Zub` are private. Can I accomplish this some other way?

Comment: I don't think so, but why not make `Zub` a regular class?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - in this case I cannot easily change the class structure (it would be a breaking change), and in any case `Zub` is using inner class features such as the implicit link to the outer class.

Comment: Don't you also need to make `Zub` a static class or provide an instance of `Bar` ?

Comment: @user207421 It will not work in this case because to initialize `Zub`, call should be `this.new Bar().new Zub();` and not `this.new Zub();`

Comment: @Thilo - you are right my sample code left a bit to be desired there, I updated it not to include `new`.

Comment: In recent Java versions you get some more type inference and can do `var z = ...`.